# Trigger indicator alert only if a condition is met on tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I need help to create a TradingView alert condition using two indicators: Stochastic and Market Liberator.
The strategy consist in triggering divergencies from Market Liberator (that has built in divergencies alerts) only if the stoch is outside of a channel.

Is it posibble?
[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NZue.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If the source code of the 'Market Liberator' indicator is closed - I'm afraid it won't be possible.

However 'Market Liberator' from your screenshot looks like a rip-off from a free public open source scripts,they have different names, one of the most popular - [vumanchu cipher B](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Msm4SjwI-VuManChu-Cipher-B-Divergences/)

In case Market Liberator is a copy of open source Cipher indicator - you only have  include one extra condition based on stochastics to the divergence alert, as is shown in example below (with the Vumanchu's market Cipher B script):

```
...
// Stoch indicator and inputs:
periodK = input(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)
// Stoch outside the 20-80 channel:
bool stochBuy = d < 20
bool stochSell = d > 80

// Divergence alerts from the MC script with additional stoch condition:
// bullish
alertcondition(buySignalDiv and stochBuy, 'Buy (Big green circle + Div)', 'Buy & WT Bullish Divergence & WT Overbought')
// bearish
alertcondition(sellSignalDiv and stochSell, 'Sell (Big red circle + Div)', 'Buy & WT Bearish Divergence & WT Overbought')
```